# How to make a generic switch for [Flags] enums in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, enums, enum-flags

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="DayButtons"/>
                <!-- and so on-->
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding blah blah blah Converter=Whatever, ConverterParameter={x: Static TooFreakingLong}">Monday</ToggleButton>
            <!-- and so on -->
        </Grid>
```

So I've defined an enum for the days of the week, and although I can make a simple Grid to show all the days of the week and toggle them at will (think for a recurring calendar day app). However, I want to apply this pattern to other `[Flags]` enums in my app and I don't want to write all this boiler #plate code over and over again. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: First thing I'd try would be an `ItemsControl` with a horizontal `StackPanel` for the `ItemsPanel`, and the `ItemsSource` bound to a `MarkupExtension` (or maybe `ValueConverter`) that enumerates the items in an `enum`. Something analagous to `{x:Type ...}`, I think maybe kinda sorta... gonna kick that around a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. The `MarkupExtension` enumerates the values of any enum type you give it, and once you've got that, you can do anything you like in an `ItemsControl` or any appropriate subclass like `ListBox`. I've written a MultiDataConverter as well, which takes a single enum flag and checks to see if it's included in a set of flags. Given that, you can write a trigger to do just about anything.

If you want the values to be always visible and be included/excluded from the set of flags by (for example) a checkbox in the item DataTemplate, that would be another MultiDataConverter.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace EdTest
{
    [Flags]
    public enum TestEnum
    {
        Foo = 1 << 0,
        Bar = 1 << 1,
        Baz = 1 << 2,
        Ping = 1 << 3,
        Pong = 1 << 4,
        Hoop = 1 << 5,
        Floop = 1 << 6
    };

    public class EnumEnumerator : MarkupExtension
    {
        public EnumEnumerator(Type type)
        {
            _type = type;
        }

        private Type _type;
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return Enum.GetValues(_type);
        }
    }
}
```

...and in the XAML, any control that displays collections can display it in any appropriate template. You could write `ValueConverters` to do more stuff with the enum values themselves.

```
<ItemsControl
    xmlns:test="clr-namespace:EdTest"
    ItemsSource="{test:EnumEnumerator test:TestEnum}"
    >
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <test:FlagCheckConverter x:Key="FlagChecker" />
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border 
                x:Name="Border"
                Padding="6" 
                Width="80" 
                Height="60" 
                BorderBrush="SteelBlue" 
                BorderThickness="1,1,0,0"
                >
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
            </Border>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="False">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FlagChecker}">
                            <!-- The DataContext value - a single enum value -->
                            <Binding />
                            <Binding 
                                Path="DataContext.TestFlags" 
                                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}" 
                                />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel 
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

And here's the MultiDataConverter that checks to see if a given enum value is one of a set of flags:

```
public class FlagCheckConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, 
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var checkValue = values[0];
        var flags = values[1];

        if (checkValue is Enum && flags is Enum)
        {
            return ((Enum)flags).HasFlag((Enum)checkValue);
        }
        return (object)false;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, 
                                object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this does half the job, doesn't do the checking if ticked. I think I can add that in myself though. Will try to add it in, will report back when I finish it off :)

Comment: @It'sNotALie. I added the flag-checker converter, but I'm having trouble binding its parameters

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Turns out making your ViewModel property public helps the binding work more better. Who knew? But I think it does what you want now.

Comment: This worked brilliantly, sorry in the delay in getting back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Awesome!